# AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'error' with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make an error handler with `discord.py`, and I'm getting an error.

The error:

```
AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'error' discord.py
```

My code:

```
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
ifistance(commands.error.MissingPermissons):
await ctx.send("You do not have permission to run this command!")
```

Answer (score 2):

There are actually no exception named `discord.ext.commands.error.MissingPermissions`, maybe you meant `discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions`

```py
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
         await ctx.send("You do not have permission to run this command!")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation this should work.

```
discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions(missing_perms, *args)
```

**Exception raised when the command invoker lacks permissions to run a command.**